# let $S_n$ be a simple random walk. $M_n$ is $\max(S_1,S_2,\ldots,S_n)$. Is $M_n$ a Markov chain? Is $M_n-S_n$ a Markov chain?

Tags: probability

> Let $S_n$ be a simple random walk. Specifically,
> $$ S_n = X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n, $$
> where $X_n$'s are i.i.d. and each takes $+1$ or $-1$ with probability $0.5$ and $0.5$ respectively. Also,
> $$ M_n = \max(S_1, S_2, \ldots, S_n).$$
>
> - Is $M_n$ a Markov chain?
> - Is $M_n - S_n$ a Markov chain?

I can see $M_n - S_n$ is a Markov chain. But when I show $M_n$ is not a Markov chain, I am not sure here what is the information we present have, i.e., what we know if we only know the present state. Is it $M_n$ or $S_n$?

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your math expressions. Check [this posting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34067) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

There is an $S_n$, but you don't know it, except in a few cases: if $M_n \ne M_{n-1}$, then for sure $M_n = S_n$.
On the other hand, if $M_n = M_{n-1} \ne M_{n-2}$, then ...  And the conditional distributions of $M_{n+1}$ in those two cases are ...

Comment: Thank you.So in this case what is included in Fn?And how can I write a convincing proof to show Mn is not Markov chain.It is clearly not,but I need a formal proof.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed the case that $ M_n = \max \{ S_1, S_2, \dotsc, S_n \} $ is not a Markov chain. We can directly compute some conditional probabilities to show this. For example, we show $ \mathbb{P} \bigl( M_4 = 1 \mid M_3 = 1 \bigr) = 2/3 $ and  $  \mathbb{P} \bigl( M_4 = 1 \mid M_3 = 1, M_2 = 1 \bigr) = 3/4. $

We have
\begin{align*}
 \{ M_3 = 1 \} & = \{ M_1 =1, M_2 = 1, M_3 = 1 \}  \cup \{ M_1 = -1, M_2 = 0, M_3 = 1 \} \\
\{ M_3 = 1, M_4 =1 \} & = \{ M_1 =1, M_2 = 1, M_3 = 1, M_4 = 1 \} \\
& \qquad \cup \{ M_1 = -1, M_2 = 0, M_3 = 1, M_4 = 1 \} \\
\{ M_2 = 1, M_3 =1 \} & = \{ M_1 =1, M_2 = 1, M_3 = 1 \} .
\end{align*}

Now, note that
\begin{align*}
\{ M_1 =1, M_2 = 1, M_3 = 1 \} & =  \{ S_1 = 1, S_2 = 0, S_3 = 1 \}
\cup \{ S_1 = 1, S_2 = 0, S_3 = -1 \} \\
\{ M_1 = -1, M_2 = 0, M_3 = 1 \} & = \{  S_1 = -1, S_2 = 0, S_3 = 1\}. \\
\{ M_1 =1, M_2 = 1, M_3 = 1, M_4 = 1 \} & =  \{ S_1 = 1, S_2 = 0, S_3 = 1, S_4 = 0 \} \\
& \qquad \cup \{ S_1 = 1, S_2 = 0, S_3 = -1, S_4 = 0 \} \\
& \qquad \cup \{   S_1 = 1, S_2 = 0, S_3 = -1, S_4 = -2 \} 
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\{ M_1 = -1, M_2 = 0, M_3 = 1, M_4 = 1 \} = \{  S_1 = -1, S_2 = 0, S_3 = 1, S_4 = 1 \} .
\end{align*}
Thus, we have
\begin{align*} 
\mathbb{P} ( M_3 = 1 ) & = 3/8, \\
\mathbb{P} ( M_3 = 1, M_4 =1 ) & = 4/16, \\
\mathbb{P} ( M_2 = 1, M_3 =1 ) & = \mathbb{P} ( M_1 = 1, M_2 =1, M_3 = 1) = 2/8 = 1/4 \\
\mathbb{P} ( M_2 =1, M_3 = 1, M_4 = 1) & = \mathbb{P} ( M_1 = 1, M_2 =1, M_3 = 1, M_4 = 1) = 3/16.
\end{align*}
This shows $ \mathbb{P} \bigl( M_4 = 1 \mid M_3 = 1 \bigr) = \mathbb{P} \bigl( M_4 = 1 \cup M_3 = 1 \bigr) / \mathbb{P} \bigl( M_3 = 1 \bigr) = 2/3 $ and $ \mathbb{P} \bigl( M_4 = 1 \mid M_3 = 1, M_2 = 1 \bigr) = \mathbb{P} (  M_2 =1, M_3 = 1, M_4 = 1) / \mathbb{P} (  M_2 =1, M_3 = 1) = 3/4. $

Now, to show $ X_{n} = M_n - S_n $ a Markov chain, let me make a little bit of change in the definition, which will make our arguments slightly easier and actually this is the standard definition. Let us set $ S_0 = 0 $ and set $ M_n = \max \{ S_0 , S_1, \dotsc, S_n \} $. This will imply that $ M_n $ takes values in $ \{ 0, 1, \dotsc, \} $. Otherwise it will takes values in $ \{ -1, 0, \dotsc, \} $. I hope that you see this change is just cosmetic and will not affect any argument.

We will use the following result : Let $ \{ \xi_i : i \geq 1 \} $ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables taking values in $ \mathbb{R}$. Let $ \{ X_n : n \geq 0 \} $ be a sequence a random variables on a state space $ {\cal S} $. Assume that $ X_0 $ is independent of the sequence $ \{ \xi_i : i \geq 1 \} $.   Suppose $ f :  {\cal S} \times \mathbb{R} \to {\cal S}  $ be a function, such that for any $ n \geq 0 $
\begin{equation*}
X_{n+1} = f ( X_n , \xi_{n+1} ) .
\end{equation*}
Then $ \{ X_n : n \geq 0 \} $ is a Markov chain.

This is a general result. For the discrete case, I give a quick proof.

For any $ k_0, k_1, \dotsc, k_{n+1} \in {\cal S} $, we have
\begin{align*}
& \mathbb{P}(X_{n+1} = k_{n+1} , X_{n} = k_n, X_{n-1} = k_{n-1}, \dotsc, X_{1} = k_1, X_0 = k_0 )  \\
& =  \mathbb{P}( X_{n+1} = f( X_n, \xi_{n+1}) = k_{n+1} , X_n = f(X_{n-1}, \xi_n) = k_n,   \dotsc, \\
& \qquad \qquad X_1 = f(X_{0}, \xi_1) = k_1, X_0 = k_0 ) \\
& =  \mathbb{P}( f( k_n, \xi_{n+1}) = k_{n+1} , f(k_{n-1}, \xi_n) = k_n,  \dotsc, f(k_{0}, \xi_1) = k_1, X_0 = k_0 ) \\
& =   \prod_{j=0}^{n} \mathbb{P} ( f ( k_j, \xi_{j+1} ) = k_{j+1} ) \mathbb{P} (X_0 = k_0).
\end{align*}
In the last equality, we have used the fact that the random variables $ \{ \xi_i : i \geq 1 \} $ are independent and hence the transformed random variables $ \{ f ( k_i, \xi_i ) : i \geq 1 \} $ (for any $ k_i \in {\cal S})$ are also independent as they are the functions of $ \xi_i $ and a non-random constant $ k_i $.

Using the above calculations, for $ i, j, x_0, x_1, \dotsc, x_{n-1} \in {\cal S} $, we have
\begin{align*}
& \mathbb{P} (X_{n+1} = j \mid X_{n} = i, X_{n-1} = x_{n-1}, \dotsc, X_{1} = x_1, X_0 = x_0 ) \\
& = \frac{  \mathbb{P}(X_{n+1} = j , X_{n} = i, X_{n-1} = x_{n-1}, \dotsc, X_{1} = x_1, X_0 = x_0 )  } { \mathbb{P}( X_{n} = i, X_{n-1} = x_{n-1}, \dotsc, X_{1} = x_1, X_0 = x_0 ) } \\
& = \frac{ \mathbb{P} ( f ( i, \xi_{n+1} ) = j ) \mathbb{P} ( f ( x_{n-1}, \xi_{n} ) = i ) \prod_{j=0}^{n-2} \mathbb{P} ( f ( x_j, \xi_{j+1} ) = x_{j+1} ) \mathbb{P} (X_0 = x_0) }{ \mathbb{P} ( f ( x_{n-1}, \xi_{n} ) = i ) \prod_{j=0}^{n-2} \mathbb{P} ( f ( x_j, \xi_{j+1} ) = x_{j+1} ) \mathbb{P} (X_0 = x_0)  } \\
& = \mathbb{P} ( f ( i, \xi_{n+1} ) = j ) . 
\end{align*}

For the other part, we observe that
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{P} (X_{n+1} = j \mid X_{n} = i ) 
= \frac{  \mathbb{P} (X_{n+1} = j , X_{n} = i )  } { \mathbb{P} (  X_{n-1} = x_{n-1}) }. 
\end{equation*}
We can write the above marginal distributions by summing over other co-ordinates as follows:
\begin{align*}
& \mathbb{P} (X_{n+1} = j , X_{n} = i )  \\
& = \sum_{k_0, k_1, \dotsc, k_{n-1} \in {\cal S} } \mathbb{P} (X_{n+1} = j , X_{n} = i, X_{n-1} = k_{n-1}, \dotsc, X_{1} = k_1, X_0 = k_0 ) \\
& = \sum_{k_0, k_1, \dotsc, k_{n-1} \in {\cal S} } \mathbb{P} ( f ( i, \xi_{n+1} ) = j ) \mathbb{P} ( f ( k_{n-1}, \xi_{n} ) = i ) \prod_{j=0}^{n-2} \mathbb{P} ( f ( k_j, \xi_{j+1} ) = k_{j+1} ) \mathbb{P} (X_0 = k_0) \\
& = \mathbb{P} ( f ( i, \xi_{n+1} ) = j)  \sum_{k_0, k_1, \dotsc, k_{n-1} \in {\cal S} }  \mathbb{P} ( f ( k_{n-1}, \xi_{n} ) = i ) \prod_{j=0}^{n-2} \mathbb{P} ( f ( k_j, \xi_{j+1} ) = k_{j+1} ) \mathbb{P} (X_0 = k_0) . 
\end{align*}
Using the same arguments, we have
\begin{align*}
& \mathbb{P} (X_{n} = i )  \\
& = \sum_{k_0, k_1, \dotsc, k_{n-1} \in {\cal S} }  \mathbb{P} ( f ( k_{n-1}, \xi_{n} ) = i ) \prod_{j=0}^{n-2} \mathbb{P} ( f ( k_j, \xi_{j+1} ) = k_{j+1} ) \mathbb{P} (X_0 = k_0) . 
\end{align*}
Therefore, we obtain that $ \mathbb{P} (X_{n+1} = j \mid X_{n} = i ) = 
\mathbb{P} ( f ( i, \xi_{n+1} ) = j)  $. This completes the proof.

This also identifies the transition matrix. Indeed, we have
\begin{equation*}
 \bigl(\bigl( p_{i,j} \bigr)\bigr) = \bigl(\bigl( \mathbb{P} ( f ( i, \xi_{1} ) = j)  \bigr)\bigr). 
\end{equation*}

Now, returning to the problem at hand, clearly $ X_0 = M_0 - S_0 = 0 $ and $ X_n = M_n - S_n \geq 0 $. Thus, the state space is $ \{ 0, 1, \dotsc \} $. Now, denoting the coin toss sequence by $ \{ \xi_{n} : n \geq 1 \} $, we note that
\begin{align*}
 S_{n+1} & = S_n +  \xi_{n+1} \\
M_{n+1} & = \max \{ S_0, S_1, \dotsc, S_n, S_{n+1} \} \\
& = \max \{ \max\{  S_0, S_1, \dotsc, S_n \} , S_{n+1} \} \\
& = \max\{ M_n, S_{n+1}  \} \\
& = \max\{ M_n, S_n +  \xi_{n+1}  \} .
\end{align*}

If $ X_n = 0 $, we have $ M_n = S_n $ and hence
\begin{equation*}
 M_{n+1}  =  \max\{ M_n, M_n +  \xi_{n+1}  \} = M_n + \max \{ 0, \xi_{n+1} \}  
\end{equation*}
which implies
\begin{align*}
  X_{ n+1}  & =  M_{n+1} - S_{n+1} \\
& = M_n + \max \{ 0, \xi_{n+1} \} - S_n - \xi_{n+1} \\
& = M_n - S_n + \max \{ 0, \xi_{n+1} \}  - \xi_{n+1} \\
& = X_n + \max \{ 0, \xi_{n+1} \}  - \xi_{n+1}  .
\end{align*}

If $ X_n > 0 $,  we have $ M_n > S_n \geq M_n - 1 $. Since $ \xi_{n+1}  \leq 1 $, we have $ S_{n+1} \leq M_n $. Thus, $ M_{n+1} =  \max\{ M_n, S_{n+1}  \} = M_n $. Thus,
\begin{equation*}
X_{ n+1}  =  M_{n+1} - \xi_{n+1} = M_n  - S_n - \xi_{n+1} = X_n  - \xi_{n+1} . 
\end{equation*}

Set $  f : \{ 0,1,2, \dotsc \} \times \{ -1,1 \} \to \{ 0,1,2, \dotsc \} $ by
\begin{equation*}
f ( x, \xi ) = \begin{cases} x - \xi & \text{ if } x > 0 \\
x +  \max \{ 0, \xi \}  - \xi & \text{ if } x = 0. \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
The result now implies that $ \{ X_n : n \geq 0 \} $ is a Markov chain. Not only that, we can identify the chain, as we may compute the transition probabilities. Check that this actually represents a random walk with elastic barrier at $ 0 $.

Answer (score 0):

1. Note that $(M_n:n)$ is nondecreasing and starts from $0$. If it were a Markov chain with transition function $p$, we'd have $P(M_n=0)= p(0,0)^n$ for all $n$. In particular $P(M_2=0) =P(M_1=0)^2$. Now clearly,  $P(M_1=0)= \frac 12$. But $M_2=0$ if and only if the first step is to the left, so $P(M_2=0)=\frac 12\ne P(M_1=0)^2$.
2. Let's examine the dynamics of $(M_n-S_n:n)$. When looking at  $M_{n+1}-S_{n+1}$. There are two cases to consider:

a. $M_n=S_n$, that is $M_n=S_n=0$.  Then $M_{n+1}=M_n+1$ if and only if $X_{n+1}=1$, in which case $M_{n+1}-S_{n+1} = M_n-S_n=0$, and otherwise $M_{n+1}=M_n$ and $M_{n+1} -S_{n+1} = M_n- S_n +1$. We can summarize the options through:
$$(*)~M_{n+1} -S_{n+1} = M_n-S_n - (X_{n+1} -1)/2.$$

b. $M_n > S_n$, that is $M_n-S_n>0$.  Then $M_{n+1}=M_n$ and $S_{n+1} =S_n+X_{n+1}$. and so $M_{n+1}-S_{n+1} = M_n-S_n -X_{n+1}$. Therefore
$$(**)~M_{n+1} -S_{n+1} = M_n -S_n -X_{n+1}.$$

Putting $(*),(**)$ together we have

$$ M_{n+1} -S_{n+1} = M_n - S_n - {\bf 1}_{\{S_n-M_n=0\}} (X_{n+1}-1)/2-{\bf 1}_{\{S_n-M_n>0\}}X_{n+1}.$$

Proving the claim. From this we can easily obtain the transition function.