# Is XnXn+1 a Markov Chain for a simple random walk?

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I'm thinking about the same scenario as this thread:
[let Sn be simple random walk.Mn is MAX(S1,S2,...,Sn).Is Mn Markov chain.Is Mn-Sn Markov chain?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/683060/let-sn-be-simple-random-walk-mn-is-maxs1-s2-sn-is-mn-markov-chain-is-mn-sn)

However, I'm not sure whether $X_nX_{n+1}$ would be a Markov chain or not? My intuition is telling me that it is a Markov chain, but how would I prove it using the definition of Markov chains? Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify, is this a product or a pair?

Comment: @YuvalPeres Product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\{X_n\}_{n \ge 1}$ are i.i.d. variables taking the values  $\pm 1$ with equal probability, then $Y_n=X_n X_{n+1}$ for $n \ge 1$ are i.i.d. variables with the same distribution. Indeed, the map
$(X_1,\dots,X_n,X_{n+1})) \to (Y_1,\dots,Y_n)$ is exactly 2 to 1, so every possible output string arises with the same probability, $2^{-n}$.